# Stop Hibernate from updating existing records

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am trying to get hibernate to write new objects each time I do a save as opposed to updating the existing records.

```
public class Risk {
    private long riskID;
    private Vehicle vehicle;
}

public class Vehicle {  
    private long vehicleID;
    private long riskID;
    private String regNumber;
    private String abiCode;
    private String make;
    private String model;
}
```

So if a write the risk to the DB. Then I change vehicle on the web and try to save the risk to the DB a second time. I would like to to have two risks in the risk table and two vehicles in the vehicle table.

Currently I am using the hibernate session Save(Object o). This is always creating a new risk in the DB but never creating a new vehicle. It is just updating the original one.

Here is my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class lazy="false" name="uk.co.test.Risk" schema="quote_engine" table="GV_RISK" >
    <id column="riskID" name="riskID" type="long">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="vehicle" class="uk.co.test.Vehicle" column="vehicleID" not-null="true" cascade="all" unique="true" />

</class>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="uk.co.test.Vehicle" schema="quote_engine" table="GV_VEHICLE">

    <id name="vehicleID" type="long" column="vehicleID">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="regNumber" type="string" column="regNumber" />
    <property name="abiCode" type="string" column="abiCode" />
    <property name="make" type="string" column="make" />
    <property name="model" type="string" column="model" />


</class>
```

Comment: How do you change the vehicle information? Where is the mapping file for `Vehicle`?

Comment: I would change it in the java.

Comment: What is your codes of saving the Risk and Vehicle ??

Comment: I think your requirements are a bit wider than what you expose, correct me if I am wrong but I think you are looking for some kind of audit feature. If I am right you should check Hibernate Envers

Comment: who should get the bounty then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the simpler way of doing that should be:

1. Saving the Risk and the Vehicle in one Session.
2. Just after you close the session, set the IDs to null.
3. And then, when needed, re-save the objects.

It's very important that you close the Hibernate session (use separated session for each save) so that the objects become detached, and when the objects become re attached Hibernates thinks that they are brand new.

Note: you should change long for Long (the primitive to the wrapper)

Comment: this is how i am currently doing it. Just thought there must be a cleaner way

Answer (score 6):

I really doubt that it's possible to make Hibernate do this auto-magically.  You're wanting to override one of the most basic behaviors of ORMs.  Their whole bag is they keep track of your objects in some Session in order to persist those updates to the database without you having to sort through those updates yourself.

If you don't want records updated, make your setters private and annotate your fields so that you get field access.  In xml, set the `default-access="field"` property on your `<hibernate-mapping>` tag.

Then you need to create a new object before adding it to your session.  Have a service with a method that looks something like this:

```
public void saveVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
  Vehicle vehicleNew = vehicle.copy();
  // Risk would be copied via risk.copy() in vehicle.copy()

  vehicleDao.save(vehicleNew)
}
```

Comment: This approach will work, but I'd rephrase your statement about '...they keep track of your objects in a Session...'.  The Session is just one level of abstraction: ultimately Hibernate is about tying Java objects to database rows, across any number of Sessions.  That's why Session.evict(), as other people suggest, won't work.

Comment: Minor remark: `vehicle.copy()` would be more object-oriented. Same for risk.

Comment: Agreed, I changed my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Probably both Risk instances have the same Vehicle instance in their many-to-one relation. If you modify this Vehicle instance you modify it for both Risk instances instead of creating a new instance.

You either have to evict the Vehicle instance or you have to save a clone instance.

I give the idea (not working code) for the two possibilities. Assume the Risk instances are r1 and r2.

1) With evict:

```
Risk r2 = r1.clone(); // or whatever you do to create your second risk instance

session.evict(r2.getVehicle());
session.save(r2.getVehicle()); // session.save(r2) also should work.
```

(pay attention: in this case r1 also refers to the vehicle instance of r2. If you don't use the r1 instance anymore, then it works. If you still want to use the r1 instance, you have to evict it and reload it from the database.)

2) With clone:

```
Risk r2 = r1.clone(); // or whatever you do to create your second risk instance

Vehicle v2 = r1.getVehicle.clone(); // create a new instance!
r2.setVehicle(v2);
session.save(r2);
```

Comment: The success of this depends on your implementation of clone().  If it copies the ID (as it will by default), this won't work because you'll have a different Java instance of a Vehicle pointing to the same persisted, logical Vehicle.

Comment: @sharakan: Might be. The code just should tell the idea. clone() is not the point. The point is either to evict vehicle or to create a new instance of vehicle.

Comment: Actually, in 1) clone() would *have* to work the way I describe, otherwise it's the same logical object and the save would be updating the same database row.  Session.evict() doesn't make the object transient again, just removes it from the Session level cache.  In 2), it would depend on whether the session used already had that Vehicle instance associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

i assume that one vehicle can have many risks yes?

risk class and risk hibernate mapping looks ok but what about vehicle?

Class should be:

```
public class Vehicle
{  
    private long vehicleID;
    private Set<Risk> risks;
    private String regNumber;
    private String abiCode;
    private String make;
    private String model;
}
```

See the set of risks (coming from the many risks to one vehicle relation). Furthermore in your vehicle mapping, you should have something like

```
<set name="risks" table="GV_RISK">
    <key column="riskID" />            
    <one-to-many class="Risk"/>
</set>
```

Hope this helps and good luck :)

Comment: No its a one to one mapping. thats why i am using the many to one but with a unique=true attribute. Which from reading many examples is how you map one-to-one.

Answer (score 2):

It would help to see the DDL for each table. You use "many to one" mappings for "one to one" association when using a unique foreign key association. If they shared the same primary key you could use one to one.

You could try making the mapping bi-directional with a one to one in your vehicle mapping but this shouldn't be necessary. Here is how it would look.

```
<one-to-one name="risk" class="uk.co.test.Risk" property-ref="riskID"/>
```

However, what you are trying to do is pretty much on point. I might just change up the class definitions a bit and double check your DDL.

For example (Keeping the hbm mappings exactly as you have them defined above):

Table structure as follows:

```
create table GV_VEHICLE (
    vehicleID int(11) not null auto_increment,
    regNumber varchar(50) not null,
    abiCode varchar(50) not null,
    make varchar(50) not null,
    model varchar(50) not null,
    primary key(vehicleID)));

create table GV_RISK (
    riskID int(11) not null auto_increment,
    vehicleID int(11),
    primary key(riskID),
    foreign key(vehicleID) references GV_VEHICLE(vehicleID));
```

Create the one to one class definitions, each with a refence to each other

```
public class Vehicle {  
    private long vehicleID;
    private String regNumber;
    private String abiCode;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private Risk risk;
}

public class Risk {
    private long riskID;
    private Vehicle vehicle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume the code that gets executed in your case is something like:

```
vehicle = new Vehicle(make, model, regNumber, abiCode)
risk = new Risk(vehicle);
session.save(risk);

vehicle.setMake(otherMake)
risk = new Risk(vehicle)
session.save(risk);
```

The problem you're having is that as soon as you call the first session.save(), both the Risk and the Vehicle object change state in Hibernate's point of view, moving from *transient* to *persistent*.  These states are detailed in the [Hibernate ORM manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-overview).

By setting the make on a persisted vehicle, you are explicitly saying that you want to be editing an existing row in the database, NOT that you want to be creating a new one.  If you want to create a new one, follow the information in the Hibernate manual, and change the second stanza to:

```
Vehicle vehicle2 = new Vehicle(otherMake, model, regNumber, abiCode)
risk = new Risk(vehicle2);
session.save(risk);
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions is to override sql-update for Vehicle with native SQL.

here is example for person:

```
<class name="Person">
<id name="id">
    <generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="name" not-null="true"/>
<sql-insert>INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, ID) VALUES ( UPPER(?), ? )</sql-insert>
<sql-update>UPDATE PERSON SET NAME=UPPER(?) WHERE ID=?</sql-update>
<sql-delete>DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE ID=?</sql-delete>
</class>
```

So you can just override sql-uptade to do insert instead ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take a look at Hibernate Envers (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
This Statment Will Help You

SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(object);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of this code. But this will just update the objects in the DB.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. The code provided already shows he knows how to save out an object.

Answer (score 1):

Use Session.evict. After you evicted an object, it won't update in the database:

```
Entity entity = ....
session.evict(entity);
entity.setA(a); // won't affect the database
```

So the object is not updated in the database, unless you explicitly call "update" or "merge" (or "saveOrUpdate").

Comment: Session.evict is intended to remove the object from the Session-level cache.  It does not un-associate the Java object from the database level information (ie, it is in a 'detached' state, it has not become transient)

Comment: But it means that the object is not updated in the database, unless you explicitly call "update" or "merge" (or "saveOrUpdate").

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is built using listeners, there are listneres for every activity in the hibernate eco system

the `DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener` is used to save or update objects using hibernate,
the `onSaveOrUpdate(org.hibernate.event.SaveOrUpdateEvent)` method will contain information about the object which is being saved.
when you call `session.save(modelObject)` your call will end up in the listener, here you can set the ID to null and the system will add a new record everytime.

[here is a sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/EventYourOwnSaveOrUpdateEventListener.htm)
[here is a blog post detailing the use of the listener](http://notatube.blogspot.in/2010/03/hibernate-using-event-listener-to-set.html)

`<property name="eventListeners">
    <map>
        <entry key="save-update"><ref local="saveUpdateListener" /></entry>
    </map>
</property>`

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know the **context** of your project, and what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

The solution to your problem might lie at another level than the technological trick you ask for.

I suspect you want somehow to keep track of the changes, that is, maintain an **history** or **audit trail**. You can do this with [Envers](http://jboss.org/envers) for hibernate. It provides the `@Audited` annotation, and enables you to query historical data.

Otherwise, you might want to re-think you classes for **immutability**. No entity should be mutable. Any change in an entity produces a new entity (something sometimes called [persistent data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) in the functional world). The new entity could be attached to the session automatically, if desired.